# Solve $(1-n)*\arctan(a*W)-n*\arctan(b*W)=\theta $

Tags: trigonometry

I try to find the values of W that met the equation

$(1-n)*\arctan(a*W)-n*\arctan(b*W)=\theta $

in which $0<n<1$, a and b are positive reals, and $\theta$ is an angle such that $-\pi/2<\theta<\pi/2$. 
would anyone know a trigonometric formula or a solution for such a problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Adding to my answer : you can simplify a little the equation defining $aW=x$ and $c=\frac ba$to have $(1-n)\,\arctan(x)+n\,\arctan(cx)=\theta$ and solve for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling that, for the most general case, an explicit solution does not exist and then you should use a numerical method for finding the zero of function
$$f(W)=(1-n) \tan ^{-1}(a W)+n \tan ^{-1}(b W)-\theta$$ Its derivative
$$f'(W)=\frac{a (1-n)}{1+a^2 W^2}+\frac{b n}{1+b^2 W^2}$$ is always positive because of the conditions $(a >0, b>0, 0 < n <1)$ so $f(W)$ is an increasing function and there is only one root.

You must notice that $f(0)=-\theta$. So, if $\theta >0$ the solution will be positive and if $\theta <0$ the solution will be negative.

If you use Newton method, the first iterate, starting with $W_0=0$, will be
$$W_1=\frac{\theta }{a (1-n)+b n}$$ which will be updated according to
$$W_{n+1}=W_n-\frac{f(W_n)}{f'(W_n)}$$

For illustration, let us use $n=0.2345$, $a=1$, $b=\pi$ and $\theta=\frac \pi 3$ with $W_0=0$. Newton iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & W_n \\
 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0.6971077 \\
 2 & 1.1848712 \\
 3 & 1.3874361 \\
 4 & 1.4120731 \\
 5 & 1.4123810 \\
 6 & 1.4123811
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much Claude. You are right. In fact I did a mistake in my equation. There is minus sign between the two arctan functions. The problem is now corrected. I also try to find a solution if I suppose that $n=p/q$ where $p$ and $q$ are positive integers.

Comment: @user425269. This makes the story very different, for sure !